# How to concatenate a string with all other strings in the list in O(n)

Tags: java, string, for-loop, concatenation

I want to concatenate a string with all other strings in the list, I am using nested-for loops, but that method is not efficient for a large list.
Can anyone help me to do it in o(n) or o(nlogn)?
Here is my code.

```
List<String> allConcatenatedStrings=new List<String>();
for(int i=0;i<listOfStrings.length-1;i++){                               
   for(int j=i+1;j<listOfStrings.length;j++){
      String temp= String.join("",listOfStrings[i],listOfStrings[j]);
      allConcatenatedStrings.add(temp);
   }
}
```

Comment: what is `tickets` did you mean `listOfStrings`

Comment: what is the inputs and what is the expected output ?

Comment: I still do not really get what you want to achieve. What string do you want to concatenate with which string?

Comment: If you need all of those `temp` strings, the code you've written is as efficient as it can be. Although I am assuming your code works (and it's similar enough to what you've posted here) -
 if that's not the case, you should also post your input, expected output and actual output (which is generally a good idea regardless). If you're trying to use this to solve some other problem, you should instead post a description of that as well as a [mcve]. Related: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: What are you doing with all of the strings? Your example code saves them to a temporary variable which is immediately lost.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) which is an efficient way to concatenate strings:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
//Inside for loop:
sb.append(stringToAppend);

//after for loop:
String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Hi Johan,
I want to concat only 2 strings at a time and then compute a logic over it. I just want an efficient way to iterate and append strings. thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use Java 8 Stream API for this:

```
List<String> listOfStrings = Arrays.asList("Hello ","World",","," apprentice");
String concatenatedString = String.join("", listOfStrings); 

System.out.println(concatenatedString); // Hello World, apprentice
```

Comment: Hi Georg,
I want to concat only 2 strings at a time and then compute a logic over it. I just want an efficient way to iterate and append strings. thanks

Comment: This is not showing up in your explanation. Then please add a comment in your question, what should happen with the strings before they are concatenated.